# Highcharts - overlapping values with the x-Axis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to create a line graph, wherein if all the values for the particular series is zero then, I want the line to be drawn on the bottom over the x-axis line. But it seems like the line of the x-axis takes the preference than the series line. Is there any way to change that?

Below is my configuration:

```
xAxis: {
    type: "datetime", 
    tickmarkPlacement: "on",
    lineWidth: 10,
    lineColor: 'red',
}, 
yAxis: {        
    min: 0, 
    minRange : 0.1,
    title: {
        text: ""
    }
}, 
plotOptions: {
    line: {
        softThreshold: false
    }
},
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/shivajyothibalavikas/twxs7mL2/3

In the above example the axis line color is red and series line color is black. but red takes the preference. I want the black line to take the preference while displaying

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to move a series line above an axis line by options in Highcharts API. As a solution, you can use the `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class and draw a custom line at the chart bottom.

```
chart: {
  ...,
  events: {
    render: function() {
      const chart = this;
      const x1 = chart.plotLeft;
      const x2 = x1 + chart.plotWidth;
      const y = chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight;

      if (!chart.customLine) {
        chart.customLine = chart.renderer
          .path().attr({
            stroke: 'red',
            'stroke-width': 10
          }).add();
      }

      chart.customLine.attr({
        d: ['M', x1, y, 'L', x2, y]
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/70d6sg2o/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer